# SWT group composite border disappers

Tags: java, swt, composite

SWT group composite border disappers when i press TAB key. Shell has 3 group composites but the disappering problem is only with one group.

```
    Group grpCustomerDetails = new Group(this, SWT.NONE);
    grpCustomerDetails.setForeground(SWTResourceManager
            .getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GRAY));
    grpCustomerDetails.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Segoe UI", 8,
            SWT.NORMAL));
    grpCustomerDetails.setText("CUSTOMER DETAILS");
    grpCustomerDetails.setBounds(10, 49, 917, 273);
           .........................
            Group grpBankDetails = new Group(this, SWT.NONE);
    grpBankDetails.setText("BANK DETAILS");
    grpBankDetails.setBounds(954, 49, 396, 214);
           ..........................
            ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(this,
            SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    scrolledComposite.setBounds(10, 335, 1340, 300);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);

    table = new Table(scrolledComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
```

Comment: Can you add a couple of snapshots to illustrate what you mean by disappearance of the border?

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar issues and it seems this is a bug in SWT:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=145662